# JavaScript Factory Pattern and OO Inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Why does using the **multipage** "type" overwrite all items in the array, but not when using the "base type" **tool**?

comment/un-comment line 52(9 from bottom of js) to test.

**JavaScript**:

Defines two types, an intended as abstract base type 'Tool' and an intended concrete type that inherits from Tool 'Multipage'.

The 'Model' object defines the valid types for dynamic creation and the getNewInstance() function returns a new instance of a valid type.

The viewmodel 'vmDesigner' holds an observable array of the multipages we create.

```
// Contsructor - Inherited
var Tool = function () {
    var self = this;

    //Public Fields
    self.id = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });
    self.type = ko.observable();
    self.xPos = ko.observable();
    self.yPos = ko.observable();
    self.xSize = ko.observable();
    self.ySize = ko.observable();
};

var MultiPage = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.tools = ko.observableArray();
};


// Inherit from Tool.
MultiPage.prototype = new Tool();
$.extend(MultiPage, Tool);



function Model(tool, multipage) {
    var types = {
        tool: tool,
        multipage: multipage
    };
    return types;
}
var model = new Model(Tool, MultiPage);

function getNewInstance(type, initisations) {
    var _Type = model[type];
    return (_Type ? new _Type().id(initisations.id) : null);
}

function vmDesigner() {
    var tools = ko.observableArray();
    return {
        tools: tools
    };
}

var vd = new vmDesigner();

var type = 'multipage';
//var type = 'tool';

var dataItem = new Tool(); //tmp data

vd.tools.push(getNewInstance(type, { id: 1, xPos: 50, yPos: 50 }));
vd.tools.push(getNewInstance(type, { id: 2, xPos: 60, yPos: 60 }));
vd.tools.push(getNewInstance(type, { id: 3, xPos: 70, yPos: 70 }));

ko.applyBindings(vd);
```

**HTML**:

The markup binds to the viewmodel and displays all items in the tools array.

```
<div id="view-design" data-bind="foreach: tools">
  Tool:<span data-bind="text: id"></span>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just 
include a link to jsbin. Link only posts are [explicitly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) on Stack Exchange as your post should stand alone from any other resource; 
consider what'd happen if jsbin went down in the future!

Comment: code added, link removed